# UWP project referencing the wrong sqlite dll

Tags: sqlite, uwp, nuget, windows-10-universal

somewhere along the line I was playing around and renamed a sqlite3.dll to sqlite3.copydll.  Now my UWP project is referencing that dll.  I have since changed it back to Sqlite3.dll what it should be but I keep getting the below when I build my project

Could not copy the file "C:\Users[username].nuget\packages\SQLite\3.13.0\runtimes\win10-x86\nativeassets\uap10.0\sqlite3.copydll" because it was not found.

I cant find where in my project it is still referencing this dll name.

Can anybody help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your .csproj as text and search for it there. Or remove reference to SQLite in VS and add it back.

Comment: Thanks uninstalling and then reinstalling enityframeworkcore. Sqlite3.dll did the trick